# Using concat on non-existing index of array

Tags: javascript

So, code below throws undefined if index is not existing in the array

Note: it's array of arrays

`arr[index] = arr[index].concat(data);`

Eventually I've fixed it with check

```
if (!array[index]) {
   array[index]=[];
}
```

Which solved the problem.

Question: is there any JavaScript trick which could solve this problem easier (less lines of code, without checks, whatever)?

Comment: Both of the proposed answers still involve a check like your original `if` statement, they just present it in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without compromising readability:

`array[index] = (array[index] ? array[index] : []).concat(data);`

Note that this and the method of using the `||` operator:

`array[index] = (array[index] || []).concat(data);`

Are both technically unsafe since they check if `array[index]` is truthy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `||` oprator:

```
arr[index] = (arr[index] || []).concat(data);
```

It will check if the `arr[index]` is a truthy value (not `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `""` and `0`).

If it is, it will use it, and if it's not, it will use the `[]` to concat to `data`.

Answer (score 1):

In ES6:

```
((a = []) => a.concat(data))(array[index])
```

but this boils down to mere code golf, although it does have the advantage that it's a few characters shorter, and the `[]` default will be used **only** if `array[index]` is missing (undefined).